# Проверить, что в строке число

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит значения через запятую. Предполагается что он ввел числа. Допустимым являются как `int`, так и `float`.
Как проверить ввел ли пользователь числа или нет ?
Я пробовала из введенной строки удалить все пробелы, точки и запятые, а затем проверить `.isdigit()`. Но мне показалось это решение слишком громоздким.

```
user_num_str = input('Enter numbers separated by commas: ')
user_num_str_check = user_num_str.replace(' ', '')
user_num_str_check1 = user_num_str_check.replace(',', '')
user_num_str_check2 = user_num_str_check1.replace('.', '')
if not user_num_str_check2.isdigit():
    print('Seams like string!')
```

Буду очень признательна, если посоветуете более простой метод.

Comment: Ваше решение не только громоздкое,  но и пропустит заранее не верные результаты. Например `0 1.2.3` явно не валидное число, но похоже пройдет вашу проверку

Comment: "Только числа" или "как минимум одно число"?

Comment: Пользователь должен ввести только числа

Answer (score 5):

Задачу можно разделить на 2 части:
1. Разбить введенные пользователем данные на элементы(через запятую)
2. Проверить, является ли введенный элемент числом

Сначала определим функцию проверки на число:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Допустим пользователь ввел строку:

```
s = "0 1.2.3, 11, 22, 33, 56.52, .225, 1.000000e+50, 1e50, NAN"
```

Тогда ее можно будет разбить на отдельные элементы:

```
lst = s.split(',')
```

И проверить, является ли каждый элемент числом или нет:

```
for element in lst:
    print(element, end='')
    if is_number(element):
        print(" - число")
    else:
        print(" - не число")
```

Вывод:

```
01.2.3 - не число
11 - число
22 - число
33 - число
56.52 - число
.225 - число
1.000000e+50 - число
1e50 - число
NAN - число
```

Обратите внимание, что такой подход признает `NAN` числом, так как `float('NAN')` обработается без ошибки. То же самое с `True` и `False`. Надо ли проверку на `NAN, True, False` - это отдельный вопрос. Во всяком случае текущая функция проверит, что с введенными данными вы дальше сможете работать как с числами.

**PS**
Использовать `try except` с приведением строки к числу возможно  возможно не самый лучший вариант. Однако я не знаю другого хорошего простого варианта проверять числа `1e50` или `.125`.
Есть несколько альтернативных вариантов:
1. Использовать регулярки, но как мне кажется они сложнее для понимания. И регулярку, которая будет одновременно воспринимать и научные способы записи вида `1e50` и записи `.5552` будет выглядеть довольно сложно. *Как говорится, у нас была проблема. Мы решили ее регуляркой,  теперь у нас 2 проблемы*
2. Использовать [str.isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnumeric#str.isnumeric)  или [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdigit)

Тогда у всех элементов в листе надо удалить лишние пробелы

```
lst = [e.replace(' ', '') for e in lst]
```

И снова проверить:

```
for element in lst:
    print(element, end='')
    if element.isdigit():
        print(" - число")
    else:
        print(" - не число")
```

Вывод:

```
01.2.3 - не число
11 - число
22 - число
33 - число
56.52 - не число
.225 - не число
1.000000e+50 - не число
1e50 - не число
NAN - не число
```

Однако, этот способ проверяет только, что строка состоит из чисел. По этому числа с плавающей точкой или с `e` не будут признаны числами. Так же это не сработает для отрицательных чисел.