# Как перечислять строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
word = input("Введите что-нибудь")
for j in (word):
     if j =="1""2":
        print("Это число")
```

Мне необходимо перечислить варианты в третьей строке. Как это сделать?

Comment: Уточните, что вы хотите перечислить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверить, что в строке число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992837/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите именно проверять только символы 1 и 2, как указано в примере, то можно написать это так:

```
word = input("Введите что-нибудь")
for j in (word):
    if j in ["1", "2"]:
        print("Это число")
```

А вообще есть функция `isnumeric()`, проверяющая, является ли строка числом, см. [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
word = input("Введите что-нибудь")
for j in (word):
     if j == "1" or j == "2":
        print("В строке есть цифра: '1' или '2'")
```